# Find nearest polygon border to a point (MySQL GIS)

Tags: mysql, gis

I have a collection of polygons in a table stored as type polygon. For a given point, I need to determine the distance to the nearest polygon border (i.e., I need to trigger a behavior change when a border is crossed - either entering or leaving a polygon, and I want to know how far the point has to move before this condition may be met).

The ST_Distance() function can provide the distance between a point and a polygon's nearest edge. Using this function I can compare a specific point against all polygons in my table and sort to find the distance to the closest one.

The ST_Distance() function, however, only returns a distance value for polygons that do not contain the point provided. If the point provided is within a polygon, the returned distance is 0 - but I need the distance to the nearest edge in this case, as well.

How can I get the distance to the nearest edge of all polygons, including those my point may be contained within?